# How to proper deal with fixed bugs in feature branches

Tags: git

It could sound trivial, maybe it is.

I have a new feature branch (say `newfeaturebranch`, branched from `develop`), but during the development a new bug is found and fixed in `develop`.

The bug is found to affect the development of the new feature. How to deal with this situation?

I assumed it would be bad practice to merge `develop` into `newfeaturebranch` (in this scenario `newfeaturebranch` is not ready to be merged back into `develop` yet), and maybe that is where I'm wrong.

Comment: "*I couldn't merge develop in newfeaturebranch, of course.*" why? Can you also not cherry-pick?

Comment: I actually assumed it is a bad practice (sort of like `release` branches)

Comment: @DocBrown ("*Please leave a comment for me after you edited*" don't forget the Follow feature. Very handy to watch for edits. Although, it does also triggers on comments and answers.)

Comment: @VLAZ: thanks, I forgot about that, indeed. However, I think it is fair to give the OP a clear hint there is someone here willing to remove a downvote and a close vote in case they make a serious effort to improve a question. I am under impression most downvoters here assume the askers capable of mindreading.

Comment: I added more detail and I think I clarified my doubt, let me know if it is not yet.

Comment: *"I assumed it would be bad practice to merge develop into newfeaturebranch"* - I still have no idea where this strange-looking idea comes from, when a feature branch is created from "develop", it is usually a "bad practice" not to merge develop back into  the feature branch in regular intervals, for example, once a day. Where did this notion of "bad practice" come from? Did someone on your team told you this nonsense? Isn't it pretty obvious that merging back from dev to feature branch regularly will committing the feature back to dev after completion far easier?

Answer (score 7):

The big red flag to me is not being able to merge the develop branch into your feature branch. This is the problem.

You haven't said which branch your feature branch is based on. If you created the feature branch from develop, you absolutely should be merging develop into feature — even if you are not fixing bugs. This is simply how git was meant to be used.

If, however, your feature branch is based on master instead, do not fix the bug in develop. Fix it in master, then merge master into develop *and* merge master into your feature branch. The master branch is the **common ancestor between develop and feature,** in this case.

There are times when it makes sense to fix the bug in the feature branch and wait for the completion of that feature before the bug fix is merged into develop or master. This is a judgment call left up to the lead developer, project management and the product owner.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Feature branches should be based on the dev branch to allow for simple merging back into the feature branch (IE: bug fixes).

---

So what happens with my team is we have the master branch, at the end of a week or the end of the sprint (depending on the goals) we'll merge everything from the dev branch to master.

With that said, all new feature branches are based on the dev branch. As bug fixes are made in dev, the feature branch can merge the latest changes back into its branch from dev. Once the test pass and the ticket is closed and the branch is merged, it's all back on the dev branch until the sprint is over unless specific conditions are set for us to merge to master for prod deployments.

Every team has a configuration a bit different but the pattern tends to be the same across the board once you reach more than two/three people on a team working from a project board of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be a defect per se. Sometimes feature work involves a class or method that is shared, and it was not apparent that it was shared before the implementation began, and the shared method wants an improvement.

Developers should absolutely be updating their branch from the parent branch regularly. Doing so just means you have deal with any conflicts sooner rather than later, and the less you let conflicts accumulate, the less difficult they are going to be to resolve.

In this case, the answer might will be a rebase instead of merge. Rebasing kind of re-writes history, but if any inspection of the work in the derived branch is ever wanted, it makes the history much easier to follow.